# How to get the output of Zsh's alias command in Swift script?

Tags: swift, macos, shell, zsh

I have added a lot of my own aliases to `~/.zshrc` to use Zsh on macOS.
I found that I could use the `alias` command to display the registered aliases.

```
% alias
myalias1='cd ...'
myalias2='cp ...'
myalias3='mv ...'
myalias4='find ...'
...
```

I wanted to use this in a Swift script, so I created the following program.
However, while the `pwd` and `ls` commands are executed correctly, the `alias` command does not output anything.

```swift
// shell.swift
import Foundation

@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
  let task = Process()
  task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
  task.arguments = args
  task.launch()
  task.waitUntilExit()
  return task.terminationStatus
}

print("--- run pwd command:")
shell("pwd")

print("--- run ls command:")
shell("ls")

print("--- run alias command:")
shell("alias")
```

```
% swift shell.swift
--- run pwd command:
/Users/myname
--- run ls command:
Applications  Documents     Library     Music       Public
Desktop       Downloads     Movies      Pictures    shell.swift
--- run alias command:
```

I am having trouble understanding the cause of this.
Please let me know if there is a solution.

Thanks.

(I used a translation tool to ask this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh`, if you run `which alias`, you'll get `alias: shell built-in command`. While there does exist a real executable at `/usr/bin/alias`, it's not the code that runs when you run the `alias` command in `zsh`. It's built-in to `zsh` itself.

You can recreate what your Swift code is doing, by running `/usr/bin/env alias`. In my case, I got an empty output.

What you'll want to do is edit your Swift code to run `zsh`, and to run `alias` within `zsh`. Equivalent to `/bin/zsh -l -c "alias"`.

Try running `shell("zsh", "-l", "-c", "alias")`.

Comment: I ran the command you provided, it displayed a few aliases that I thought were registered by default. However, the aliases that I have added to my `~/.zshrc` were not displayed.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's what the `-l` flag was for, I thought it would make it a login shell (which should source `~/.zshrc`), but it appears not. Try `/bin/zsh --login -c "alias"`

Comment: I got the same result. I tried to write `echo "hello"` in `~/.zshrc`, but it doesn't output. I wrote `echo "hello2"` in `~/.zprofile`, `hello2` was output. It seems that `~/.zshrc` is not loaded.

Comment: `.zshrc` is only sourced by interactive shells. You would need to add the `-i` option as well to the command invocation.

Comment: Running `zsh -l -i -c alias` in the terminal gave me the ideal result.
But run `shell("zsh", "-l", "-i", "-c", "alias")` on a Swift script, the shell is prompting for input and will not proceed.

Comment: Running the same thing in a Python script gave the expected results. Thank you all!

Comment: @Mac Well it's running in interactive mode, so I guess taht makes sense. Perhaps `zsh` is waiting for `eof` or something?

Comment: The cursor blinks and ready to type. I can only escape with `Ctrl` + `C`. The results of `alias` command will not be output.

Comment: @Mac try hooking up a pipe to standard input and feed it an empty input

Comment: Do you mean `"" | zsh -l -i -c "alias"`?

Comment: Yes, but the equivalent in Swift, using the standardInput of Process.

Comment: I tried the same thing using Swift's `Process` and `Pipe`, but the result was the same. It seems that there is a limit to doing these things in Swift. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Mac This doesn't have much to Swift, this is the `Process` API (formerly known as `NSTask`) from Foundation. It's decades old, and pretty full featured. We're missing something here, I just don't know what it is.